# Last updated by is showing logged in user's name

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, seam

In my project, in base entity class, we have last updated by and last updated date field. Other entity classes are extending base entity class. To update last updated by, there is a method in base entity. To this method, @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations are used. This is causing a problem. Say one admin A updates a user profile, then last updated by is updated as A in DB. But if another admin B logs into application and see the updated user profile, the last updated by is shown as B.(Here B has just viewing user profile not yet updated nad saved.) While fetching user details to view his profile, user object is used which is extending the base entity class. Any solution to overcome this problem?Please let me know if any other details required.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate` instead.

Comment: I tried using this. But it wont update the value while saving i.e., A has created a user and the last updated by of that user is A.Now, admin B edits the same user, then also the last updated by value in DB is A as the base entity method is called after persist of user entity

Comment: You may check this [Interceptors and events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html). Tell mi if it works this with the interceptors.